# Suggested Grails plugins to make Grails a good CMS option

Tags: grails, content-management-system

We are trying to look for plugins for Grails to make a CMS site. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Check out Weceem at
http://www.weceem.org/weceem/
I've never used it but apparently it can be used as a stand-alone site or integrated into an existing grails app as a plugin.

Comment: Weceem is the most actively developed one I know of

Comment: There are a few other ones in the repository, but the authors all combined their efforts to focus on Weceem.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Alfresco plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/alfresco), though it's likely more focused on the document management side of Alfresco (it allows both Document Management and Web Content Management).